# Data Fetch issue in Java

Tags: java

From a Java application, if I need to fetch 100 000 records from any RDBMS. What are the things I should consider? will it be fetched by a simple select statement?

Comment: What do you mean with huge records?

Comment: I mean to say suppose you have a table say Employee which has got 100000 records. Now your application has to fetch all the records and display in UI in a J2EE application and the application is using Spring MVC with Hibernate as the ORM layer.

Comment: So... there are no huge records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the things I should consider?

The most obvious thing is that it could take a long time to transfer 100,000 "huge" records over a JDBC connection.

You might want to look at alternatives ... like a database specific data extraction tool of some kind.

> will it be fetched by a simple select statement?

If you are willing to wait long enough for the transfer to compete, yes.

---

> Suppose that application has to fetch all the records and display in UI in a J2EE application and the application is using Spring MVC with Hibernate as the ORM layer.

More things to consider:

- Attempting to display 100,000 records to a user in a single page is a bit crazy.  No user is going to want to scroll through 100,000 records.
- If you are doing this kind of thing via an ORM, you are liable to us an inordinate amount of server-side memory.

My advice: don't fetch all 100,000 records.  Instead, fetch the first N, and implement a scheme that allows the user to page through the records.